Which parameters need to be changed to improve repairs?
Could you  please explain, what are the parameters need
to be changed to improve repair in Casandra.
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: 
Repair command #1158 failed with error Repair session 
b836f570-700d-11ef-9447-377b26201515 
for range [(9164824941183028599,-9164226683701868787], 
(6868832037534058657,6892120122899442963], 

(9091534174371255880,9164824941183028599]] failed with error 
[repair #b836f570-700d-11ef-9447-377b26201515 on test/tab_ext

[(9164824941183028599,-9164226683701868787], 

(6868832037534058657,6892120122899442963], (9091534174371255880,9164824941183028599]]] 
Validation failed in test-east-prod-cassandra-vm0.az.com/10.2.1.5.:7000. 

Check the logs on the repair



There aren't many things that need to be tuned when it comes to Cassandra repairs. In fact, it mostly works out-of-the-box without the need to configure anything.
However, the question that needs to be asked is: what problem are you trying to solve? Without knowing what issue you are running into, it is impossible to say what you need to do with repairs.
In my experience, unless a cluster runs into infrastructure issues (VMs pausing because of "noisy neighbours", network disruptions or outages, server outage due to hardware faults, etc) then repairs work fine. The problem is when the cluster gets overloaded so replicas miss some (or a lot of) writes (dropped mutations) which leads to inconsistencies.
To make the replicas consistent again, the nodes need to be repaired but if they are already overloaded, repairs add even more load to the cluster and it becomes a vicious cycle.
Two things that are really important are:

Make sure that your cluster is sized correctly so it can cope with peak writes and peak reads, not just the average read/write loads.
Aim for a node density of 1TB or less.

If you follow these two guidelines, you don't have to worry about repairs. Cheers!

As a side note, it's important to provide sufficient detail when asking questions because it helps contributors like me to provide the best response to you. For reference, see How to ask on Stack Exchange and the article Asking Good Cassandra Questions I've published on the official Apache Cassandra website. Thanks for being part of the community!

Hi Erick,
Thanks for your inputs.
If run full repair, frequently I'm getting error below.

error: Repair job has failed with the error message: Repair command #1158 failed with error Repair session b836f570-700d-11ef-9447-377b26201515 for range [(9164824941183028599,-9164226683701868787], (6868832037534058657,6892120122899442963], (9091534174371255880,9164824941183028599]] failed with error [repair #b836f570-700d-11ef-9447-377b26201515 on test/tab_ext[(9164824941183028599,-9164226683701868787], (6868832037534058657,6892120122899442963], (9091534174371255880,9164824941183028599]]] Validation failed in test-east-prod-cassandra-vm0.az.com/10.2.1.5.:7000. Check the logs on the repair

I ran individual table and table-level repairs and they were successful. Please let me know how we can handle this issue.
